# How to detect edge in complex flame image using Python?

Tags: python, opencv, filter, gradient, edge-detection

For my combustion related research I need to detect a flame front using any kind of edge detection.

I have applied a combination of filters and thresholding steps to achieve my goal, however they proof to be inaccurate. Any idea is welcome! I have a csv file of the complete image containing 3 columns, i.e. x-coordinates, y-coordinates, intensity [counts].

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xp2X.png)

[area of interest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSO9T.png)

I hope someone can help me solve this problem, since it will really boost my research.

Code:

```
        # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    """
    Created on Thu Dec 29 12:22:11 2022
    
    @author: luuka
    """
    
    #%% Import packages
    import os
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    from copy import copy, deepcopy
    import imutils
    
    #%% Start
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    plt.close("all")
    
    #%% Main functions
        
    
    def read_image(data_dir, nx, ny):
        
        XYI = np.genfromtxt(data_dir, delimiter=",", skip_header=1)
        X = XYI[:,0].reshape(ny, nx)
        Y = XYI[:,1].reshape(ny, nx)
        I = XYI[:,2].reshape(ny, nx)
        
        return X, Y, I, XYI
        
    def plot_image(fig, ax, X, Y, I, brightness_factor):
    
        intensity_plot = ax.pcolor(X, Y, I, cmap='gray')
        
        intensity_plot.set_clim(0, I.max()/brightness_factor)
        
        ax.set_xlabel('$x\ [mm]$')
        ax.set_ylabel('$y\ [mm]$')
        
        # Set aspect ratio of plot
        ax.set_aspect('equal')
        
        bar = fig.colorbar(intensity_plot)
        bar.set_label('Image intensity [counts]') #('$u$/U$_{b}$ [-]')
        
        return X, Y, I, XYI
    
    #%% Auxiliary functions
    
    def showInMovedWindow(winname, img, x, y):
        cv2.namedWindow(winname)        # Create a named window
        cv2.moveWindow(winname, x, y)   # Move it to (x,y)
        cv2.imshow(winname, img)
        
    def format_coord(x, y, Z):
        xarr = X_zoom[0,:]
        yarr = Y_zoom[:,0]
        if ((x > xarr.min()) & (x <= xarr.max()) &
            (y > yarr.min()) & (y <= yarr.max())):
            
            col = np.searchsorted(xarr, x) - 1
            
            # col = len(xarr) - (np.searchsorted(np.flip(xarr), x)) # flame 4
            
            row = len(yarr) - (np.searchsorted(np.flip(yarr), y))
            
            z = Z[row, col]
            
            return f'x={x:1.4f}, y={y:1.4f}, z={z:1.4f}   [{row},{col}]'
        
        else:
            
            return f'x={x:1.4f}, y={y:1.4f}'
        
    def format_coord_Z1(x, y):
        return format_coord(x, y, I_zoom)
    
    # def format_coord_Z1_1(x, y):
    #     return format_coord(x, y, contrast)
    
    def format_coord_Z2(x, y):
        return format_coord(x, y, blur_gaus)
    
    # def format_coord_Z2_1(x, y):
    #     return format_coord(x, y, binary_zoom_x)
    
    def format_coord_Z3(x, y):
        return format_coord(x, y, pixel_density_gradient_combined)
    
    def format_coord_Z4(x, y):
        return format_coord(x, y, thresholding_1)
    
    # def format_coord_Z5(x, y):
    #     return format_coord(x, y, img_blur)
    
    # def format_coord_ZX1(x, y):
    #     return format_coord(x, y, average_pixel_density_gradient_y)
    
    # def format_coord_ZX2(x, y):
    #     return format_coord(x, y, binary_zoom1)
    
    #%% Main
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        
        #%%% Define data to read 
        
        # READ INFO OF THE RAW IMAGES
        main_dir = "Y:/"
        project_name = "flamesheet_2d_day16"
        project_dir = main_dir + project_name
        calibration_txt_dir = project_dir + "/Properties/Calibration/DewarpedImages1/Export/B0001.txt"
        record_name = "Recording_Date=221223_Time=132754_01"
        
        x_info, y_info = read_xy_dimensions(calibration_txt_dir)
        nx, ny = 653, 1040
        
        record_correction_csv_dir = project_dir + "/" + record_name + "/Correction/Reorganize frames/Export_02/"
        # record_correction_csv_dir = "Export_02_flame_4/"
        
        #%%%% Define image number
        image_nr = str("3319")
        filename = "B" + str(image_nr)+ ".csv" 
        
        image_dir = record_correction_csv_dir + filename
        
        #%%% Read data
        
        X, Y, I, XYI = read_image(image_dir, nx, ny)
        
        x_left, x_right = 0, 5
        y_bottom, y_top = -16, -10
        
        x_left, x_right = -3.4, 16
        y_bottom, y_top = -16, -8
        
        # x_left, x_right = -4, 35
        # y_bottom, y_top = -23, 50
        
        # x_left, x_right = X.min(), X.max()
        # y_bottom, y_top = Y.min(), Y.max()
        
        xarr = X[0,:]
        yarr = Y[:,0]
        col_left = np.searchsorted(xarr, x_left) - 1
        col_right = np.searchsorted(xarr, x_right) - 1
        
        row_top = len(yarr) - (np.searchsorted(np.flip(yarr), y_top))
        row_bottom = len(yarr) - (np.searchsorted(np.flip(yarr), y_bottom))
        
        X_zoom = X[row_top:row_bottom, col_left:col_right]
        Y_zoom = Y[row_top:row_bottom, col_left:col_right]
        I_zoom = I[row_top:row_bottom, col_left:col_right]
        
        # X_zoom = X
        # Y_zoom = Y
        # I_zoom = I
        
        
        #%%% Figure 1 : raw image
        fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
        
        brightness_factor = 1
        plot_image(fig1, ax1, X_zoom, Y_zoom, I_zoom, brightness_factor)
        ax1.format_coord = format_coord_Z1
        ax1.set_xlim(np.array([x_left, x_right]))
        ax1.set_ylim(np.array([y_bottom, y_top]))
        
        #%%% Figure 2 : Gausian blur the raw image
        fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
        
        # src = I_zoom
        # ksize = 3
        # area = ksize*ksize 
        # kernel = np.ones((ksize,ksize),np.float32)
        # blur_gaus = cv2.filter2D(src/area, -1, kernel)
        
        src = I_zoom  # Input image array
        size = 3
        ksize = (size, size) # Gaussian Kernel Size. [height width]. height and width should be odd and can have different values. If ksize is set to [0 0], then ksize is computed from sigma values.
        sigmaX = 0 #3 # Kernel standard deviation along X-axis (horizontal direction).
        blur_gaus = cv2.GaussianBlur(src, ksize, sigmaX)
        
        brightness_factor = 1
        plot_image(fig2, ax2, X_zoom, Y_zoom, blur_gaus, brightness_factor)
        
        #%%% Brighten image by blending gray image and blurred image (alpha and beta are the blending weights of the images)
        fig22, ax22 = plt.subplots()
        src1 = I_zoom # First input image array
        alpha = -2 # -1 # Weight of the first array elements
        src2 = blur_gaus# Second input image array
        beta = 8 # 3 Weight of the first array elements
        gamma = 0 # Scalar added to each sum
        bright = cv2.addWeighted(src1, alpha, src2, beta, gamma)
        
        brightness_factor = 1
        plot_image(fig22, ax22, X_zoom, Y_zoom, bright, brightness_factor)
        
        #%%% Figure 3 : gradient of Gaussian blurred image
        
        fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots()
        pixel_density = deepcopy(blur_gaus)
        
        pixel_density_ravel = pixel_density.ravel()
        
        pixel_density_gradient = np.gradient(pixel_density)
        pixel_density_gradient_x = np.abs(pixel_density_gradient[0])
        pixel_density_gradient_y = np.abs(pixel_density_gradient[1])
        pixel_density_gradient_combined = pixel_density_gradient_x + pixel_density_gradient_y
        
        
        brightness_factor = 1
        plot_image(fig3, ax3, X_zoom, Y_zoom, pixel_density_gradient_combined, brightness_factor)
        ax3.format_coord = format_coord_Z3
        
        
        #%%% Figure 4 : thresholding of gradient image
        fig4, ax4 = plt.subplots()
        
        thresholding_1 = deepcopy(pixel_density_gradient_combined)
        
        threshold_gradient = 20
        thresholding_1[thresholding_1 < threshold_gradient] = 0
        
        
        brightness_factor = 4
        plot_image(fig4, ax4, X_zoom, Y_zoom, thresholding_1, brightness_factor)
        ax4.format_coord = format_coord_Z4
        
        
        #%%% Figure 5 : thresholding of raw image + thresholding of gradient image (previous step)
        fig5, ax5 = plt.subplots()
        
        # threshold_pixel = 575
        # threshold_gradient = threshold_gradient
        
        # final1 = np.ones(I_zoom.shape)
        # final2 = np.ones(I_zoom.shape)
        
        # final1[I_zoom < threshold_pixel] = 0
        # final2[pixel_density_gradient_combined < threshold_gradient] = 0
        
        # final = final1 + final2
        
        # final[final == 1] = 0
        
        final1 = deepcopy(I_zoom)
        final2 = deepcopy(pixel_density_gradient_combined)
        
        final = final1 * final2
        
        brightness_factor = 8
        plot_image(fig5, ax5, X_zoom, Y_zoom, final, brightness_factor)
        
        
        
            
        order = 0
        
        if order == 0:
            #%%% Open -> close [0]
            fig_opem, ax_open = plt.subplots()
            src = thresholding_1
            size = 3
            kernel_shape = cv2.MORPH_RECT # cv2.MORPH_RECT MORPH_ELLIPSE
            kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(kernel_shape, (size,size))
            opening = cv2.morphologyEx(src, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations = 1)
            
            brightness_factor = 1
            plot_image(fig_opem, ax_open, X_zoom, Y_zoom, opening, brightness_factor)
            
            
            fig_close, ax_close = plt.subplots()
            src = opening
            size = 3
            kernel_shape = cv2.MORPH_RECT # cv2.MORPH_RECT MORPH_ELLIPSE
            kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(kernel_shape, (size,size))
            closing = cv2.morphologyEx(src, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations = 1)
            
            brightness_factor = 1
            plot_image(fig_close, ax_close, X_zoom, Y_zoom, closing, brightness_factor)
        
        else:
        
            #%%% Close -> open [1]
            fig_close, ax_close = plt.subplots()
            src = final
            size = 3
            kernel_shape = cv2.MORPH_RECT # cv2.MORPH_RECT MORPH_ELLIPSE
            kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(kernel_shape, (size,size))
            closing = cv2.morphologyEx(src, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations = 1)
            
            brightness_factor = 1
            plot_image(fig_close, ax_close, X_zoom, Y_zoom, closing, brightness_factor)
            
            
            fig_opem, ax_open = plt.subplots()
            src = closing
            size = 2
            kernel_shape = cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE # cv2.MORPH_RECT MORPH_ELLIPSE
            kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(kernel_shape, (size,size))
            opening = cv2.morphologyEx(src, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations = 1)
            
            brightness_factor = 1
            plot_image(fig_opem, ax_open, X_zoom, Y_zoom, opening, brightness_factor)
            
        #%%% Figure 6 : Gausian blur the raw image
        fig6, ax6 = plt.subplots()
        
        src = closing  # Input image array
        size = 3
        ksize = (size, size) # Gaussian Kernel Size. [height width]. height and width should be odd and can have different values. If ksize is set to [0 0], then ksize is computed from sigma values.
        sigmaX = 0 #3 # Kernel standard deviation along X-axis (horizontal direction).
        blur_gaus = cv2.GaussianBlur(src, ksize, sigmaX)
        
        brightness_factor = 1
        plot_image(fig6, ax6, X_zoom, Y_zoom, blur_gaus, brightness_factor)
        
        #%% Canny
        fig_canny, ax_canny = plt.subplots()
        
        data = pixel_density_gradient_combined/pixel_density_gradient_combined.max()
        data = 255 * data
        
        src = data.astype(np.uint8)
        threshold1 = 0.05
        threshold2 = 0.2
        apertureSize = 3
        L2gradient = False
        edges = cv2.Canny(src, threshold1, threshold2)
        
        brightness_factor = 8
        plot_image(fig_canny, ax_canny, X_zoom, Y_zoom, src, brightness_factor)
```

Comment: You might check out OpenCV2 Canny.  https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d22/tutorial_py_canny.html

Comment: Thanks! It is not clear to me which thresholding values I need in the function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I want to make it clear that *there is no edge in this image* so no edge detection method can work.

Also, any limit that you might draw is arbitrary and will differ from people to people, unless you have a well-defined physical model that gives meaning to the light intensities.

For a quick and dirty approach, reduce the resolution (this will denoise) and binarize with a constant threshold.

[image]